# To which folder did I install the Faenza icon theme to?

Tags: 11.10, settings, faenza

I downloaded the Faenza icon theme. I also installed the Advanced Settings app from the Software Centre. I double-clicked the Faenza install file and it opened a Terminal list of commands which I followed. Easy enough. Except that I noticed that you're supposed to install it as Root (so that it can copy the icon files into the file system rather than Home. If you don't install as Root, then a bunch of the icons aren't copied across.

This meant that it installed twice, as you can by the screenshot.

I simply want to remove the non-Root files but don't know where they copied to. Does anyone know where they would be?

[image: Faenza icon theme]

Comment: What does `locate Faenza-Ambiance/in*` show?

Comment: I typed that into Terminal and got no result.

Comment: Try this: `sudo updatedb && locate Faenza-Ambiance/in`

Comment: do you have a `.local/share/icons/` folder hidden in your home directory?

Comment: No I don't have that folder in my home directory.

Comment: I found it. The hidden folder is simply home/.icons. I deleted the folders and they vanished from the menu in the screenshot above.

Comment: This question has been solved. It does not need to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

[Gonzozo solved the problem in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101086/to-which-folder-did-i-install-the-faenza-icon-theme-to#comment116821_101086):

> I found it. The hidden folder is simply home/.icons. I deleted the folders and they vanished from the menu in the screenshot above.